# .Net stuttering while freeing up memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection, freeze

I'm working on a DirectX 12 based app in c# with .Net Framework 4.8, which interface to DirectX using a c++/cli project.

Regardless of the context, I'm noticing heavy stuttering (the app freeze for around 500ms) when the profiler show the memory usage to drop, even though no garbage collection is taking place, as shown in the image *(app freeze two times, corresponding to the presence of two memory drops in the selected region)*:
[image]

The displayed memory usage and drops are part of the wanted implementation behavior, my problem are is just the app freezing.
From CPU Usage profiling, the CPU usage also drops, but I cannot find anything app-related that explain this issue.

How should I go about solving this, is there any good practice regarding memory allocation in .Net I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is not unmanaged memory being freed? I don't really see any way for managed memory to be released unless a GC is run. I would be somewhat suspect of the unmanaged code and/or DirectX doing something funky. A CPU-profiler should give some hint to what the application is doing. Note that a GC and finalizer may run in the background, I would also be careful trusting the "no GC occurred" to much.

Comment: Thanks, you were right: it was unmanaged memory asynchronously freed on directx, after waiting for GPU operations to complete, but a managed call to the unmanaged side would cause the app to synchronize to those releases and freeze.